# Magento 2 USPS Log Not Created in Debug Mode

Tags: usps

So I have debug set to Yes on the USPS shipping method but no log is being created in var/log. I am in developer mode and I have checked all scopes to be sure debug is enabled. Anyone else have this issue on Magento 2.1.10?

Comment: I'm having this issue too, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope, still no solution